# Flex4: Disable List's Scroll Bar

Tags: actionscript-3, list, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am currently creating a flex mobile application and am using a list to display data. I don't want to be able to disable or hide the scroller/scroll bar of the list. Does anyone know how to do this? Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on which component you're using, but take a look at the `horizontalScrollPolicy` and `verticalScrollPolicy` properties. Here's the link to the docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#horizontalScrollPolicy

Usage is basically:

```
someComponent.horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
```

Comment: +1 [This might be a better link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#style:horizontalScrollPolicy) to follow, it points specifically to the documentation for this style as defined by the `List` (rather than the old Flex 3 `Container` class).

Comment: @PeterGibson Hi. Thanks for the link. I want to still want the user to be able to scroll the list though. The example you gave does hide the scrollers, but it also disables the scrolling of the list. Do you know any alternatives the the example you gave me? Is it possible to set the alpha to 0 of a scroller?